# Probability of Probabilties: Probabilities of random variables having same or similar distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I have been looking for some resources on these types of meta probability questions, but haven't been lucky so far.

The question I was pondering, say I suspect someone to be an alien and I would like to find out if that is true or not. A strategy I have thought of is, gather a bunch of reaction samples from people I am certain of that they aren't aliens, meaning, I ask them "Are you an alien?" and record what the reaction is. I basically assume that the number of reactions a human could give to that question is finite (albeit possibly huge).
Then I ask the suspect the question. If I have encountered the reaction before, I guess that someone is actually human. However, if the reaction is different, I guess that the suspect is an alien.

My question is, what is the probability that the guess is correct?

The way I tried to formalize this was:

Let X1,..., Xn be i.i.d variables defined on the same probability space which map into a finite set Z.
Let Y be similar, but we do not know its distribution and how it is related to the X variables.
Let S be a subset of Z such that the probability that the X variables map into S, but Y doesn't, is nonzero.

Given the event that the X variables map into S, but Y doesn't, what is the probability that Px=Py, where Px and Py are the respective image measures?

However, this isn't really formally correct since I am still missing a probability space for the meta probability. And here is where I am stuck.

Does this whole embargo make sense and can anyone point me in a helpful direction please?
Also sorry for the lack of convenient math notation, but I am on the phone and just had to get this question out there.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to describe a "meta" probability space in which the values of random variables are themselves probability spaces/random variables/etc., but this isn't useful for practical modeling, because random variables in the same probability space can already depend on each other in complex, hierarchical ways. For example, a [Bayesian network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network) specifies a collection of random variables in terms of their dependencies and [conditional distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution). I'd recommend studying Bayesian methods - they provide a clarifying perspective on most practical inference problems.

For your alien problem, a sensible quantitative approach might be: Ask known humans the question until you get enough duplicates that only 5% of the answers you've heard are unique; infer from this that a human will give one of the known responses with probability $.95$. Then if your suspect gives a novel response, you can reject the hypothesis that they're human at significance level $p=0.05$. This is just a [hypothesis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#Interpretation), though. If you want to calculate an actual probability that the suspect is human, you also need a [prior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability) that the suspect is human as well as a model for aliens' responses (not just humans') in order to apply [Bayes' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem):

$$P(\text{human}|\text{unique response})=\frac{P(\text{unique response}|\text{human})P(\text{human})}{P(\text{unique response})}$$

where

$$P(\text{unique response})
=P(\text{unique response}|\text{human})P(\text{human})
+P(\text{unique response}|\lnot\text{human})P(\lnot\text{human}).$$

Comment: Thanks for the input. I definitely want to look into Bayesian methods. However, I really am more interested in these "meta" probability spaces than the question or practical inference problems. I was just writing the question for people to see where I am coming from.
Do you know if there is a theory on this or just keywords I could use to research this?

Comment: My guess is that there isn't much theory on it because it turns out not to be particularly interesting or useful, since "random variables that depend on other random variables" is something you can do inside a single probability space. Maybe another answerer will prove me wrong, though!

Comment: How can you do them inside a single probability space though?
I mean that is one of the things that tripped me up, I know what the event space is for the condition (the X variables mapping into S, but Y not)
But it is clear to me that the event Px=Py must be from some other event space.
So, bridging those 2 spaces would help me out immensely if you could please explain how it is done or alternatively what to look up.

Comment: Hmm, I think you could achieve something equivalent by having X and Y depend on Z (in the Bayesian network sense) and looking at $P(Z\in A)$ where A is the set of Z values that give X and Y the same conditional distribution, i.e. (if the variables are discrete) $A=\{z:\forall k,P(X=k|Z=z)=P(Y=k|Z=z)\}$.