# Probabilities and Logical Implications

Tags: probability, logic

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous random variables over $\mathbb{R}$.
Suppose I knew for certain i.e w.p 1 that $E[X]>E[Y]$ then of course $X\neq_d Y$ (i.e $X$ and $Y$ must not share the same distribution):
$$E[X]>E[Y] \implies X\neq_d Y $$

What if I only know the LHS w.p $0<\alpha<1$ what is a well formulated claim, if any, that I can make about RHS.

The general question is how to reason about an expression in the form
$$\text{if }(p \implies q) \text{ then }(P[\mathbb{I}[p]]=\alpha) \implies ?$$

where $\mathbb{I}[\cdot]$ is a binary indicator.

Comment: $\mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathbb E[Y]$ are deterministic...

Comment: Yes im skipping some notation to get to the point. We assume we don't know the expectations exactly for instance if we've only observed a set of finite samples.

Comment: Of course that $\mathbb E[X]\neq \mathbb E[Y]\implies X\neq_d Y$ is always true...

Comment: For a mathematical statement to have a probability, it needs to refer to an event in a probability space. The statement $EX>EY$ is *about* random variables in a probability space, but it's not an event within one. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143380/probability-of-probabilties-probabilities-of-random-variables-having-same-or-si/4143527

Comment: Since you mentioned reasoning from observed samples, you might be interested in statistical inference methods like hypothesis testing and Bayesian networks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the pointers, I realize this isnt the most well formulated question I'm mostly just looking for hints on how to imporve the statement.